How can I solve a multi-delay differential equation?
I hope this message finds you well. I am currently trying to solve a delay differential equation (DDE) with multiple
constant delays and plot the solution, but I am encountering difficulties, and I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can offer.
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}y(t) + \frac{2}{t+\frac{3 \pi}{2}} y(t+\frac{3 \pi}{2}) + \frac{t}{(t+ 2 \pi)} y(t+ 2 \pi)=0$$
The exact solution is $y(t) = t \sin(t)$.
Thank you in advance!
Please find attached my bellow my code (it doesn't work for me):
  (* Define the initial history for y(t) for t <= 0 and for t > 20 *)
history[t_] := t Sin[t];  (* For t <= 0 *)

(* Define the equation with delays *)
eq = D[y[t], {t, 2}] + (2/(t + 3 π/2)) y[t + 3 π/2] + (t/(t + 2 π)) y[t + 2 π] == 0;

(* Define the history beyond t > 20 (assuming continuity of the function y(t)) *)
extendedHistory[t_] := t Sin[t];  (* Extension for t > 20 *)

(* Solve the delay differential equation with initial history for both t <= 0 and t > 20 *)
solution = NDSolve[
   {
    eq, 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == history[t], (* History for t <= 0 *)
    y[t /; t > 20] == extendedHistory[t]  (* History for t > 20 *)
   },
   y, 
   {t, 0, 20} (* Solve from t = 0 to t = 20 *)
];

(* Plot the solution *)
Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. solution], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}, PlotLabel -> "Numerical Solution"]


DSolve and NDSolve in current state on Mathematica version 14.1 can't solve this kinds equation.

Please show us the Mathematica code for the equation so we can play with it easier.

There are no boundary conditions, so it is not clear for what problem this exact solution is given :)

@AlexTrounev it's an ODE it depend only on time, so there is no boundary condition, it doensn't depend on spcae.

@MariuszIwaniuk I added my code as you requested, but it doens't work for me.

Read my first comment !!!

@walidfssm To solve this second order delayed differential equation on $0\le t\le 20$ we need initial history at $t>20$ as well:)

@walidfssm Anyway, we can try numerical method proposed in our paper and implemented in Mathematica on  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1155/2022/1753992

@AlexTrounev I tried to add initial condition for the case of $t>20$. even that it still doens't work. your work can solve the problem, but it' s complicated for my work. I can't go that further. I can add some extra condition or what ever to just obtain a code that works.

This problem can be solved with our method described in the paper
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
       2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
  Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]];
k0 = 4; M0 = 8; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
var1 = Array[v1, {nn}]; var2 = Array[v2, {nn}]; 
u10[x_] := var1 . int1[x] + a01; u11[x_] := var1 . Psi[x]; 
u20[x_] := var2 . int1[x] + a02; 
u21[x_] := var2 . Psi[x]; T = 20; eq12 = 
 Table[{-u20[t] + u11[t]/T == 0, 
    u21[t]/T + 
      2/(T t + 3 Pi/2) If[
        t + 3 Pi/2/T >= 1, (T t + 3 Pi/2) Sin[T t + 3 Pi/2], 
        u10[t + 3 Pi/2/T]] + 
      T t/(T t + 2 Pi) If[
        t + 2 Pi/T >= 1, (T t + 2 Pi) Sin[T t + 2 Pi], 
        u10[t + 2 Pi/T]] == 0}, {t, xcol}] // Flatten;
eqs = Join[eq12, {u10[0] == 0, u20[0] == 0}]; varM = 
 Join[var1, var2, {a01, a02}]; sol = 
 FindRoot[eqs, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]];

In the code above we used the Euler wavelets with 64 collocation points. Visualization
Plot[{Evaluate[u10[t/T] /. sol], t Sin[t]}, {t, 0, T}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Numeric", "Exact"}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}]


Absolute error
ListPlot[
 Table[{t, Abs[Evaluate[u10[t/T] /. sol] - t Sin[t]]}, {t, T xcol}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Delta]y"}, Filling -> Axis]


In a case of general solution $t(c_1 \sin(t)+c_2 \cos(t))$ code should be modified as follows
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
       2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
  Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]];
k0 = 4; M0 = 8; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
var1 = Array[v1, {nn}]; var2 = Array[v2, {nn}]; 
u10[x_] := var1 . int1[x] + a01; u11[x_] := var1 . Psi[x]; 
u20[x_] := var2 . int1[x] + a02; u21[x_] := var2 . Psi[x]; 
soln[c1_, c2_] := 
 Module[{T = 20}, 
  eq12 = Table[{-u20[t] + u11[t]/T == 0, 
      u21[t]/T + 
        2/(T t + 3 Pi/2) If[
          t + 3 Pi/2/T >= 
           1, (T t + 3 Pi/2) (c1 Sin[T t + 3 Pi/2] + 
             c2 Cos[T t + 3 Pi/2]), u10[t + 3 Pi/2/T]] + 
        T t/(T t + 2 Pi) If[
          t + 2 Pi/T >= 
           1, (T t + 2 Pi) (c1 Sin[T t + 2 Pi] + c2 Cos[T t + 2 Pi]), 
          u10[t + 2 Pi/T]] == 0}, {t, xcol}] // Flatten;
  eqs = Join[eq12, {u10[0] == 0, u20[0] == c2}]; 
  varM = Join[var1, var2, {a01, a02}]; 
  sol = FindRoot[eqs, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]; 
  sol] 

Example of usage
sol1 = soln[1, 1];

Plot[{Evaluate[u10[t/T] /. sol1], t (Sin[t] + Cos[t])}, {t, 0, T}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Numeric", "Exact"}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}] 



A more general solution is (C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t])t. Do you specify some boundary conditions to select a particular solution?

@yarchik Please, see update to my answer :)

Very nice solution!

@AlexTrounev Thank you so much for your effort. very nice solution.

@walidfssm You are welcome!
